# How To Add Two Signals In Matlab As Inputs For The Lsim Command For A System?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have to create an input signal that has a pulse for a short period of time. That is from 1s - 2s, the rest of the signal should be a constant at 5. In short, the signal should be a straight line at 5, and should have a bump of 5.05 from time 1s - 2s. This tells me that I should create two signals and add them up. I am not being able to do that. If you have any other way I could do this, it'd be great. I'd appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do it you need to know your sample rate.  Let's say your sample rate is 10 per second (i.e. 10 Hz), and you wanted your time series to go from 0 sec to 5 seconds.  You would do the following.

```
sampRate = 10;
timeLen  = 5;

inputSig = ones(timeLen * sampRate, 1) * 5;

sigStart = 1;
sigEnd = 2;
inputSig((sigStart+1)*sampRate:sigEnd*sampRate) = inputSig((sigStart+1)*sampRate:sigEnd*sampRate) + 0.05;
```